# Angular material upgrade to V15 and customize CSS on MDC-based components

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I upgraded my angular project which uses Angular material to v15. I ran mdc migration. I created the angular material theme based on our website's color scheme. But I have a section where the MDC components like text fields, tabs which need to be customized as that section has darker background compared to the rest of the website and my regular theme doesn't work for that area. Before I used to use customization like the following:

```
::ng-deep .black-textbox .mat-form-field-label {
  color: white !important;
}

::ng-deep .black-textbox .mat-form-field-underline {
  background-color: white !important;
}

::ng-deep .black-textbox .mat-form-field-ripple {
  background-color: white !important;
}
```

What is the best way to go about doing this with v15/v16? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Go to their migration page and see what have changed, in stead of .mat-xxx its become .mdc-xxx so i would go and check for the components that is conserned also to check if the dom structure is a bit different. Else just run it locally lookup the class names in you browser and replace the names from there.